# the functions create different sized circles

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm having a problem where when I run the code the two images formed should be mirror images of each other (at 90 degrees to each other) but instead the second image, which is tilted 90 degrees, is much larger and starts at a much bigger radius than the first. is there a way to make both identical?

[image]

```
import turtle

START_RADIUS = 10
RADIUS_INCREMENT = 5
turtle.speed(100)
def tangential_circles(total_circles):
    for x in range (total_circles):
        global START_RADIUS
        global RADIUS_INCREMENT
        turtle.circle(START_RADIUS)
        START_RADIUS+= RADIUS_INCREMENT
    '''Draw tangential circles.'''

    
def move_to(position):
    '''Move turtle to position. Pick the pen up before moving and put the pen
        back down afterwards.
    '''
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.setpos(position)
    turtle.pd()
 


def main():
    turtle.speed(100)
    move_to((-50,0))
    tangential_circles(10)

    move_to((100,-10))
    turtle.rt(90)
    

    tangential_circles(10)
    turtle.exitonclick()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Hint: don't use global variables.

Comment: What @MarkTolonen said. You're incrementing `START_RADIUS` and then never putting it back to its original value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead. The problem is that you are passing your variables as globals so the changes taking place in the variable START_RADIUS are saved and carried forward. To avoid that, you can remove the globals and pass the variables to the function.

There might be other ways to do it, but this worked for me.

```
import turtle

START_RADIUS = 10
RADIUS_INCREMENT = 5
turtle.speed(100)


def tangential_circles(total_circles, start_rad, rad_incr):
    for x in range(total_circles):
        turtle.circle(start_rad)
        start_rad += rad_incr
    '''Draw tangential circles.'''


def move_to(position):
    '''Move turtle to position. Pick the pen up before moving and put the pen
        back down afterwards.
    '''
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.setpos(position)
    turtle.pd()


def main():
    move_to((-50, 0))
    tangential_circles(10, START_RADIUS, RADIUS_INCREMENT)

    move_to((100, -10))
    turtle.rt(90)

    tangential_circles(10, START_RADIUS, RADIUS_INCREMENT)
    turtle.exitonclick()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

During execution of the function 'tangential_circles' your global variable 'START_RADIUS' is modified. When you call the function the second time the last value of 'START_RADIUS' is used for the next circle. If you want to draw exactly the same figure again you need to copy 'START_RADIUS' to a local variable. Modify your function like this:

```py
def tangential_circles(total_circles):
    r = START_RADIUS
    for x in range (total_circles):
        turtle.circle(r)
        r += RADIUS_INCREMENT
```

Or multiply instead of incrementing:

```py
def tangential_circles(total_circles):
    for x in range (total_circles):
        turtle.circle ( x * RADIUS_INCREMENT )
```